# Getting my USB headset to work with ChrUbuntu kernel

Tags: usb, logitech, headset, chrubuntu

I just want to make an audio call on my brand new Ubuntu 12.04 ChruBuntu kernel from my Chromebox. For that purpose, I am trying to use 2 devices:

A logitech headset H555: http://www.logitech.com/en-au/webcam-communications/internet-headsets-phones/6810

As that is not working, I also tried a webcam, Logitech, not sure about the model, but seems to be this one: http://mobile.logitech.com/en-us/support/webcams/legacy-devices/3382

The big issue is that it doesn't show in my settings -> Sound.

[image]

After some search on internet, I understood that dmesg might help...

The usefull output seems to be these lines:

```
[34253.108017] EXT4-fs (sda5): couldn't mount RDWR because of unsupported optional features (ff000000)
[35669.588208] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 5
[35679.288375] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 5
[35682.803740] usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[35682.894724] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a01
[35682.894735] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[35682.894741] usb 2-1.5: Product: Logitech USB Headset
[35682.894746] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Logitech
[36676.293997] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[36676.294067] init: Temporary process spawn error: No such file or directory
[36744.413838] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 6
[36784.204411] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 21 using ehci_hcd
[36784.294884] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a01
[36784.294895] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[36784.294902] usb 1-1.6: Product: Logitech USB Headset
[36784.294906] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: Logitech
```

I am still searching a lot of forums and blogs but cannot find any answer on what I should do next.

Any hint?

EDIT:

Other info:

```
user@ChrUbuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor
Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation
Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC
Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series
Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
SMBus Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200
Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 05)

01:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9300
Wireless LAN adaptor (rev 01)

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)

user@ChrUbuntu:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards

0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xe0600000 irq 46
```

More info:

```
user@ChrUbuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 046d:0a01 Logitech, Inc. USB Headset
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 046d:08f5 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Messenger Communicate
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.
```

EDIT AGAIN:

As suggested by John S Gruber, here are the lines of /var/log/udev that contains v046D
The complete output is here: http://pastebin.com/fWwCeeuu

```
UDEV  [2.342758] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=002
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/002/003
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/002/003
DEVNUM=003
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=Logitech_USB_Headset
ID_MODEL_ENC=Logitech\x20USB\x20Headset
ID_MODEL_ID=0a01
ID_REVISION=1013
ID_SERIAL=Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:010100:010200:
ID_VENDOR=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
MAJOR=189
MINOR=130
PRODUCT=46d/a01/1013
SEQNUM=1286
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3
UPOWER_VENDOR=Logitech, Inc.
USEC_INITIALIZED=2342558
```

and

```
KERNEL[2.180449] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/001/005
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=255/255/255
MODALIAS=usb:v046Dp08F5d0100dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFiscFFipFF
PRODUCT=46d/8f5/100
SEQNUM=1282
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=255/255/255
UDEV_LOG=3
```

and

NOTE: These lines only appear for v046DpC52 that seems to be the mouse + keyboard that are actually working fine, I have NO line containing v046Dp0A01 (Headset) or v046Dp08F5 (webcam)

```
UDEV  [2.077186] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input4 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input4
EV=17
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Receiver
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Receiver
ID_MODEL_ID=c52b
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.1:1.2
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_1_1_2
ID_REVISION=1201
ID_SERIAL=Logitech_USB_Receiver
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=02
ID_VENDOR=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
KEY=ffff0000 0 0 0 0
MODALIAS=input:b0003v046DpC52Be0111-e0,1,2,4,k110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,11A,11B,11C,11D,11E,11F,r0,1,6,8,am4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101a"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1:2"
PRODUCT=3/46d/c52b/111
PROP=0
REL=143
SEQNUM=1239
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=2067428
```

Re-Re-Edit:

```
Aug  5 21:47:59 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1318.128047] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
Aug  5 21:48:02 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1320.940343] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Aug  5 21:48:06 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1324.493860] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
Aug  5 21:48:06 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1324.580875] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=08f5
Aug  5 21:48:06 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1324.580885] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Aug  5 21:48:06 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1324.580891] usb 2-1.1: Product: Camera
Aug  5 21:48:06 ChrUbuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
Aug  5 21:48:06 ChrUbuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Aug  5 21:48:21 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1339.603896] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
Aug  5 21:48:21 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1339.782120] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
Aug  5 21:48:21 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1339.868933] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=08f5
Aug  5 21:48:21 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1339.868948] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Aug  5 21:48:21 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1339.868958] usb 2-1.1: Product: Camera
Aug  5 21:48:21 ChrUbuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
Aug  5 21:48:21 ChrUbuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Aug  5 21:48:21 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1340.291313] usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
Aug  5 21:48:22 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1340.382321] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a01
Aug  5 21:48:22 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1340.382332] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug  5 21:48:22 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1340.382338] usb 2-1.5: Product: Logitech USB Headset
Aug  5 21:48:22 ChrUbuntu kernel: [ 1340.382343] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Logitech
Aug  5 21:48:22 ChrUbuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5"
Aug  5 21:48:22 ChrUbuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
```

lsusb -v output 
(the terminal is too short to display the first lines:

```
      Right Front (R)
    iChannelNames           0 
    iTerminal               0 
  AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                13
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      4 (MIXER_UNIT)
    bUnitID                 9
    bNrInPins               2
    baSourceID( 0)         12
    baSourceID( 1)          6
    bNrChannels             2
    wChannelConfig     0x0003
      Left Front (L)
      Right Front (R)
    iChannelNames           0 
    bmControls         0x00
    iMixer                  0 
  AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
    bUnitID                 1
    bSourceID               9
    bControlSize            1
    bmaControls( 0)      0x01
      Mute Control
    bmaControls( 1)      0x02
      Volume Control
    bmaControls( 2)      0x02
      Volume Control
    iFeature                0 
  AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
    bTerminalID            14
    wTerminalType      0x0301 Speaker
    bAssocTerminal          0
    bSourceID               1
    iTerminal               0 
  AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                12
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
    bTerminalID            11
    wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
    bAssocTerminal          0
    bNrChannels             1
    wChannelConfig     0x0001
      Left Front (L)
    iChannelNames           0 
    iTerminal               0 
  AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
    bUnitID                 2
    bSourceID              11
    bControlSize            1
    bmaControls( 0)      0x03
      Mute Control
      Volume Control
    bmaControls( 1)      0x00
    iFeature                0 
  AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                12
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      4 (MIXER_UNIT)
    bUnitID                 7
    bNrInPins               1
    baSourceID( 0)          2
    bNrChannels             1
    wChannelConfig     0x0001
      Left Front (L)
    iChannelNames           0 
    bmControls         0x00
    iMixer                  0 
  AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
    bTerminalID            10
    wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
    bAssocTerminal          0
    bSourceID               7
    iTerminal               0 
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           0
  bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       1
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
    bTerminalLink          12
    bDelay                  1 frames
    wFormatTag              1 PCM
  AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                23
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
    bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
    bNrChannels             2
    bSubframeSize           2
    bBitResolution         16
    bSamFreqType            5 Discrete
    tSamFreq[ 0]         8000
    tSamFreq[ 1]        11025
    tSamFreq[ 2]        22050
    tSamFreq[ 3]        44100
    tSamFreq[ 4]        48000
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
    bmAttributes            9
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Adaptive
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x00c0  1x 192 bytes
    bInterval               1
    bRefresh                0
    bSynchAddress           0
    AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
      bLength                 7
      bDescriptorType        37
      bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
      bmAttributes         0x01
        Sampling Frequency
      bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
      wLockDelay              0 Undefined
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       2
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
    bTerminalLink          12
    bDelay                  1 frames
    wFormatTag              1 PCM
  AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                23
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
    bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
    bNrChannels             1
    bSubframeSize           2
    bBitResolution         16
    bSamFreqType            5 Discrete
    tSamFreq[ 0]         8000
    tSamFreq[ 1]        11025
    tSamFreq[ 2]        22050
    tSamFreq[ 3]        44100
    tSamFreq[ 4]        48000
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
    bmAttributes            9
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Adaptive
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0060  1x 96 bytes
    bInterval               1
    bRefresh                0
    bSynchAddress           0
    AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
      bLength                 7
      bDescriptorType        37
      bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
      bmAttributes         0x01
        Sampling Frequency
      bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
      wLockDelay              0 Undefined
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        2
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           0
  bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        2
  bAlternateSetting       1
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
    bTerminalLink          10
    bDelay                  0 frames
    wFormatTag              1 PCM
  AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                23
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
    bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
    bNrChannels             1
    bSubframeSize           2
    bBitResolution         16
    bSamFreqType            5 Discrete
    tSamFreq[ 0]         8000
    tSamFreq[ 1]        11025
    tSamFreq[ 2]        22050
    tSamFreq[ 3]        44100
    tSamFreq[ 4]        48000
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
    bmAttributes            9
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Adaptive
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0060  1x 96 bytes
    bInterval               1
    bRefresh                0
    bSynchAddress           0
    AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
      bLength                 7
      bDescriptorType        37
      bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
      bmAttributes         0x01
        Sampling Frequency
      bLockDelayUnits         2 Decoded PCM samples
      wLockDelay              1 Decoded PCM samples
```

EDIT (Once again..)

After

> gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf Change options snd-usb-audio
>   index=-2 to `options snd-usb-audio index=1
>
> Then plug in your headset again.

I lost the Digital output and my headphones became output:

[image]

```
user@ChrUbuntu:~$ modprobe snd-usb-audio
FATAL: Module snd_usb_audio not found.
```

Syslog:

```
Aug 10 22:51:56 ChrUbuntu kernel: [   27.765382] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Aug 10 22:51:58 ChrUbuntu kernel: [   28.964259] usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
Aug 10 22:51:58 ChrUbuntu kernel: [   29.055118] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a01
Aug 10 22:51:58 ChrUbuntu kernel: [   29.055128] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug 10 22:51:58 ChrUbuntu kernel: [   29.055135] usb 2-1.5: Product: Logitech USB Headset
Aug 10 22:51:58 ChrUbuntu kernel: [   29.055139] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Logitech
Aug 10 22:51:58 ChrUbuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5"
Aug 10 22:51:58 ChrUbuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 4 was not an MTP device
```

Cards:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xe0600000 irq 46
```

Devices:

```
  2: [ 0- 8]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 0- 7]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 3]: digital audio playback
  5: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  6: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  7: [ 0- 3]: hardware dependent
  8: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
  9: [ 0]   : control
 33:        : timer


user@ChrUbuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ChrUbuntu 3.2.7 #1 SMP Tue Jun 26 23:10:36 PDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 110: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 114: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
user@ChrUbuntu:~$ locate snd-usb-audio
/lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/kernel/sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/kernel/sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
/lib/modules/3.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
/lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic/kernel/sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
user@ChrUbuntu:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   59804  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     29062  1 
snd_hda_codec_cirrus    20544  1 
rfcomm                 25259  0 
joydev                 16448  0 
hid_logitech_dj        16448  0 
ath3k                  12352  0 
bluetooth             116787  10 rfcomm,ath3k
snd_hda_intel          24640  3 
ath9k                 117696  0 
snd_hda_codec          67292  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              12390  1 snd_hda_codec
mac80211              198984  1 ath9k
ath9k_common           12643  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              363295  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    21066  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
snd_pcm                61378  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
memconsole             12352  0 
cfg80211              140766  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
r8169                  45120  0 
snd_timer              21094  1 snd_pcm
rtc_cmos               16448  0 
snd_page_alloc         12757  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
nm10_gpio              12352  0 
user@ChrUbuntu:~$
```

Comment: The next step may be to search /var/log/udev for the matching device. Please look for and copy to your question any block of information from that file containing v046D (capital D). We know the device is on the bus from lsusb. The udevd daemon should have discovered it and created a linux device for it.

Comment: Thank a lot, John, I copied the Log. From my basic knowledge, I discovered that the first part repeat for each of my 3 logitech devices and the second part is there only for the keyboard+mouse that are working pretty well. So, I guess that something is missing between these parts of code...

Comment: Here if the complete output: http://pastebin.com/fWwCeeuu

Comment: From the udev output we can see that a device is added to your system to communicate with it as a generic USB device, but that's no help. It isn't being recognized as a sound device. What is the product called? How is it described on the box? Is it a new version of a similar (Logitech?) product? How long has it been on the market?

Comment: Could you also provide the output of `lsusb -v`? The output from /var/log/syslog from when you plug it in may also be helpful.

Comment: lsusb -v is too long to be posted I tried to select relevant lines, and I added the brand, model, and syslog to the initial post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using a custom kernel, since linux 3.2.7, as listed in your `uname -a` output has a higher version number than the current release 12.04 kernel (3.2.0-29). (It's also lower than the current 12.10 kernel).

Looking at the output of `lsmod` we can see that there is no *module* snd_usb_audio in the list of loaded modules. You need that to run most USB audio devices that use the USB standard for audio devices.

The locate command lists several snd_usb_audio modules, but not for your running kernel.

- I'd suggest you use a standard kernel and see if that doesn't detect and support your headphones.
- If you have compiled the custom kernel yourself, you may wish to make that work, I'd suggest making snd_usb_audio a module by changing the corresponding kernel config variables, recompile the kernel, and run `make modules_install` as well as `make install` to reinstall the remade custom kernel. I recognize that this kernel may have snd_usb_audio linked into the kernel, in which case I don't know why the custom kernel isn't using it properly to install the necessary audio devices.

> CONFIG_SND_USB=y
>      CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO=m

Comment: Seems a great explanation. The kernel is coming out a Chromebox and ChrUbuntu: http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.be/2012/04/chrubuntu-1204-now-with-double-bits.html Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `lsusb -v` output, the Linux kernel's ALSA subsystem snd_usb_audio should be allocating the control and pcm devices for your device and drive them.

Looking at [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/usb-audio-under-debian-squeeze-818951/) post, it might be worth trying that solution:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Change `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` to `` `options snd-usb-audio index=1 ``

Then plug in your headset again.

---

If this doesn't work, please run lsmod and put the output in your question.

If snd-usb-audio doesn't appear in the list please try `modprobe snd-usb-audio`, and  capture /var/log/syslog from when you do. At that time please also check lsmod and /proc/asound/devices and /proc/asound/cards and look for the interface again.

Comment: Hello, thank a lot for your answer, I added some details at the end of my long post. I also voted for your answer as you are kindly helping me.

Comment: Would you please enter the command `locate snd-usb-audio` and add the output to your question? That file should be found. Could you also add the output from `lsmod`.

Comment: Could you please also include the output from `uname -a` in your question to compare against the locate output?

Comment: Done: user@ChrUbuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ChrUbuntu 3.2.7 #1 SMP Tue Jun 26 23:10:36 PDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Would you please enter the command `locate snd-usb-audio` and add the output to your question? That file should be found. Could you also add the output from `lsmod`? I'm looking for the reason for  `FATAL: Module snd_usb_audio not found`.